# TypeError: axiosCookieJarSupport is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I am building a electron app with React, TypeScript. I am using a JavaScript library in this app '5paisajs' I have created type definition files for this library and placed them in \node_modules\5paisajs folder. When I run the app, it launches but I get a runtime error

```
Uncaught TypeError: axiosCookieJarSupport is not a function
    at Object../node_modules/5paisajs/index.js (index.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Module../src/app.tsx (app.tsx:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object.0 (main.js:84402)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at bootstrap:856
    at bootstrap:856
```

Can you please help understand what is going wrong in this?
Please let me know if you want to see any config files.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code in `node_modules/5paisajs/index.js`? It looks like it's having the problem on line 21 and maybe it's specific to how you are importing axios-cookiejar-support?

Comment: Here is the index.js file - https://github.com/5paisa/5paisa-js/blob/dev/index.js